# Asterisk full log parser

Tags: php, ajax, asterisk

I want to make a log parser for for an Asterisk PBX, but don't know where to start.
I figured it out what i need from the log. the lines that i need look like this:
`[Apr 12 11:11:56] VERBOSE[3359] logger.c:     -- Called 111`
the number in VERBOSE[....] are the same for 1 call.

The first thing that i have to do is get the lines that contain that VERBOSE number so i can identify that call. the second thing is to read the text, there are some standard texts so it won't be hard to recognize.

The thing is that i would like to read it real time (the file is written real time), and display it in a webpage. PHP or Ajax.

The thing that i want to do is, show up rows in a webpage as users call. and the new call to be added under the current/answered call.

Any tips, examples would be great.

Thanks,
Sebastian

Comment: it's likely not log parser but some sort of `tail` utility

Comment: with the info i get from the log, i need to add some cols in the table and leave some blank to be completed. also according to the info i got from the log i need to make custom colored rows. any ideeas?

Comment: sure. You have at least 4 separate tasks here: 1. getting NEW entries from log, 2. parsing them, 3. sending them to the browser using AJAX (or, better, COMET) call, and then 4. Colorize them. While latter three are trivial ones, the N1 is quite hard to implement. So, it's not colors, bells and whistles should be your concern but getting data from the log.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Can you give me some examples with COMET or ajax, or short terms so i can search myself. any ideas on Task 1?

Comment: COMET and ajax both easily googlable. for the task 1 An unix command-line utility called `tail` coming to my mind. It's getting last rows from the text file.

Comment: I know the `tail` command but how to get the info into a variable?

Comment: Thare are some possible solutions in my mind, but I never did it in real. So, better I'd suggest you to rewrite your question, accenting it on this one problem, so, it may draw attention from someone who may be done it already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it in 2 programs that can work as simple CGI programs.

1. First program parses log and show date and call identifier. Such identifier will be link to 2nd program. In Python you can use regexp:

   ```
   # 1st group - date, 2nd - callid
   RX_VERBOSE =  re.compile(r'(.*) VERBOSE\[(\d+)\] ')

   def make_link(call_id):
       return(' <a href="show_call.cgi?call_id=%d>%d</a>' % (call_id, call_id))

   def show_calls(logfn):
       call_ids = []
       f = open(logfn)
       for line in f:
           rx = RX_VERBOSE.search(line)
           if rx:
               call_id = int(rx.group(2))
               if not call_id in call_ids:
                   print('%s %s' % (rx.group(1), make_link(call_id)))
                   call_ids.append(call_id)
       f.close()
   ```
2. This program will show the lines that has call identifier:

   ```
   def show_call_datails(logfn, call_id):
       search_str = ' VERBOSE[%s] ' % call_id
       f = open(logfn)
       for line in f:
           if search_str in line:
               print(line.rstrip())
       f.close()
   ```